# Qt- Moving a QGraphicsItem causes artifacts.Leaves trailes behind

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, mousemove, qgraphicsitem

When i move a QGraphicsItem, weird artifacts stay behind.Some parts of the item dont render,other render...
In the note.cpp i have a shape

```
QPainterPath Note::shape()const{
   QPainterPath path;
   //    path.addRect(0, 0, 50, 20);
   path.moveTo(0, -80.0);
   path.lineTo(0.0, 80.0);
   path.lineTo(80.0, 0.0);
   //    path.lineTo(75.0, -30.0);
   path.closeSubpath();
   return path;
}
```

In the paint function

```
QPointF *points = new QPointF[3];
points[0] = QPointF(0,-80);
points[1] = QPointF(0,80);
points[2] = QPointF(80,0);
painter->drawPolygon(points,3);
```

[image]
[image]
The first picture shows that all are fine when i start the app.
The second picture shows that when i move a triangle with the mouse, it gets sliced.Other times it leaves some trails and doesn't render all parts of the triangle
Here is the github link for the project.
[Github link](https://github.com/rivenblades/Qt-QGraphicsItem-MovingArtifacts)

To reproduce, just move a triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem` for efficiency only repaint the section that returns `boundingRect()` method, in your case `QRect(0, 0, 80, 80)` only returns half the necessary area since the coordinate `(0, -80)` is outside the boundingRect. The solution is:

```cpp
QRectF Note::boundingRect() const {
    return QRectF(0, -80, 80, 160) ;
    // or
    // return shape().boundingRect();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right.I need to tell it the x,y(origin) of my shape, and width, height of it.Thanks